# AngularJS Translate Static Files Loader

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I just recently started learning angular and i'm a bit lost with this code, could some one help me with this. Like, how i can modify it to use my en_US.json which is located at locale/locale-en_US.json.

```
 .factory("$translateStaticFilesLoader", ["$q", "$http",
    function(a, b) {
        return function(c) {
            if (!c || !angular.isString(c.prefix) || !angular.isString(c.suffix)) throw new Error("Couldn't load static files, no prefix or suffix specified!");
            var d = a.defer();
            return b({
                url: [c.prefix, c.key, c.suffix].join("../locale/locale-"),
                method: "GET",
                params: ".json"
            }).success(function(a) {
                d.resolve(a)
            }).error(function() {
                d.reject(c.key)
            }), d.promise
        }
         $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm feeling a little dumb. I managed to fix my code and the solution was >

app.js(main)

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: '../locale/locale-',
      suffix: '.json'
    });
}]);
```

services.js

```
app.factory("$translateStaticFilesLoader", ["$q", "$http",
function(a, b) {
    return function(c) {
        if (!c || !angular.isString(c.prefix) || !angular.isString(c.suffix)) throw new Error("Couldn't load static files, no prefix or suffix specified!");
        var d = a.defer();
        return b({
            url: [c.prefix, c.key, c.suffix].join(""),
            method: "GET",
            params: ""
        }).success(function(a) {
            d.resolve(a);
        }).error(function() {
            d.reject(c.key);
        }), d.promise;
    }
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('');
}]);
```

I just needed to copy the static translate from the original source and paste it to my services and leave all the parameters empty.

Answer (score 0):

Static file loading with `$translate` is handled by an additional external *.js file that you need to load in. This contains the `$translateStaticFilesLoader` factory mentioned here.

You can manually copy in the factory like @ALoppu did, but a better approach is to actually load the external script right after `angular-translate.js`:

```
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-translate.min.js"></script>    
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

You can get the latest copy of `angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js` on [GitHub here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files/master/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js).